# Return query result as a map of json

Tags: postgresql, cockroachdb

I have a table user_roles:

| id | role | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | admin | 2021-10-27 |
| 2 | developer | 2021-10-28 |

I would like to have the result returned as a map of json just like the format below:

```
{
  "1":{
    "id":"1",
    "role":"admin",
    "created_at":"2021-10-27"
  },
 "2":{
    "id":"2",
    "role":"developer",
    "created_at":"2021-10-28"
  },
}
```

Which SQL (Postgres) query should I use to get a result like this?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html? Did you try something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`json_object_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

```
SELECT json_object_agg(id, to_json(*)) FROM user_roles
```